# Dynamically constructed variable (jQuery syntax)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to construct global vars inside of jQ .each(). I get 'invalid left-hand side in assignment' error...

```
'prefix_' + $(this).attr('id') = $(this).method();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
window['prefix_' + $(this).attr('id')] = $(this).method();
```

Comment: one question, if I want to then push that var into an array, how do I reference it? `myArray.push(window['prefix_' + $(this).attr('id')]);` ...?

Comment: Yep, that should do it.